# switch a variable value everytime a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to toggle/switch the value of the variable every time a button is clicked so 
that

```
var ccw = $("#part1, #part3, #screw1, #screw3, #screw5, #part7");
```

turns into

```
ccw = $("#part4, #part2, #screw2, #screw4");
```

and

```
cw = $("#part1, #part3, #screw1, #screw3, #screw5, #part7");
```

turns into

```
cw = $("#part4, #part2, #screw2, #screw4");
```

my code

```
  var angle;
  var reverseAngle;
  var angleCW;
  var angleCCW;
  var cw = $("#part1, #part3, #screw1, #screw3, #screw5, #part7");
  var ccw = $("#part4, #part2, #screw2, #screw4");

  function machine() {
  angle = 0;
  reverseAngle = 0;
  $("#part10").unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggle(function() {

    });

     ccw = $("#part1, #part3, #screw1, #screw3, #screw5, #part7");
     cw = $("#part4, #part2, #screw2, #screw4");

    $("#part10").hide();
    $("#part11").show();
    $("#part10").delay(800).fadeIn();
    $("#part11").delay(800).fadeOut();
      reverseRotation();
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    reverseRotation();
    cw.rotate(angleCW);
    ccw.rotate(angleCCW);
    $("#part9").animate({
      opacity: "-=0.1",
      top: "-=1"

    }, 200 , function() {
      if($("#part9").css("opacity") <= 0){
       $(this).css({
        opacity: '1',
        top: '0'
      });
    }
    });
  },50);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind a click event on whatever button you want to use to swap the variables like this:

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
    var temp = cw;
    cw = ccw;
    ccw = temp;
});
```

Comment: @TravisMichaelHeller No prob!  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could bind a true/false switch on the click event and use a ternary operator to decide which one to use.

```
var switch_array = true;
$('#button').click(function(){
    switch_array = !switch_array;
    rotation = switch_array ? cw : ccw;
});
```

Now the `rotation` variable will always contain the selectors you want.